# ActiveMQ Advisory messages with store and forward networks of brokers

Tags: web-services, jms, activemq-classic

My MQ setup is the following:

[image: mq setup topology]

Producer A and Producer B are sending data to virtual topic:*VirtualTopic.test*

Consumer A is consuming messages from queue *Consumer.A.VirtualTopic.test* and consumer B is consuming messages from *Consumer.B.VirtualTopic.test*.

All consumers and producers have both brokers defined with failover notation which (together with virtual queues) enables us to survive broker failure. So in case that one of brokers fails, consumer is connected to the other one, where it can continue receiving messages.

I would like to know when any (or both) producers disconnect. For that I subscribed to advisory topic: ActiveMQ.Advisory.Producer.Topic.VirtualTopic.test.

And here comes my trouble... When all the consumers are connected as is shown in picture and Producer A goes down, only consumer A receives advisory message with producerCount 0, while the other consumer doesn't receive it.
I would expect that mq brokers would provide summarised number of producers in advisory messages (2 in that case) and only when both producer would disconnect advisory message with producerCount=0 would be received on both consumers.

Can this be achieved somehow? Or at least that advisory messages that broker1 sends would be forwarded to broker2 which will be delivered to consumerB?